# Unicode text in Shiny app

Tags: r, unicode, shiny

I'm trying to make Shiny print text output that includes emoji. Unfortunately, it seems that rather than printing the emoji, it prints the Unicode numbers of the different symbols, like so:

[image]

Here is a simple example of Shiny not handling emoji. it loads three emoji from an `emoji.json` file:

```
{"emoji":["","",""]}
```

And simply renders the text in `app.R`

```
library(jsonlite)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
ui <- fluidPage(textOutput("emoji"))
server <- function(input, output) {
   output[["emoji"]] <- renderText({
     "emoji.json" %>% 
     read_json() %>% 
     .[["emoji"]] %>% 
     str_c(collapse="")
   })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It feels like there must be some transformation I need to do somewhere, but I can't tell what. Also this is being done on a Windows 10 computer using R version 3.5.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends on the encoding of your `emoji.json` file. When I copied your example file into TextEdit (I'm on a Mac), converted it to plain text, and saved it as a `.json` with `UTF-8` encoding, the emojis displayed correctly both in TextEdit and in the shiny app you posted.

I though the problem might be due to encoding, so I replaced the emojis with their hex equivalents and saved the file with `Western (Windows Latin 1)` encoding so they appeared as plain text of hex numbers.

Getting them to display properly in Shiny simply required combining `as.integer` to convert from Hex and `intToUtf8` to render them as `UTF8` characters.

JSON file with Hex representations of the emoji in `Western (Windows Latin 1)` encoding:

```json
{"emoji":["0x0001F605","0x0001F612","0x0001F62B"]}
```

Shiny app:

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
ui <- fluidPage(textOutput("emoji"))
server <- function(input, output) {
    output[["emoji"]] <- renderText({
        "emoji3.json" %>% 
            read_json() %>% 
            .[["emoji"]] %>% 
            sapply(function(x) {
                intToUtf8(as.integer(x))
            }) 
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The Emoji are properly displayed:

[image: The Emoji are properly displayed]